# How to install an older 1.3 version of Symfony framework using Composer or PEAR tools?

Tags: symfony1, composer-php, pear

How to install an older 1.3 version of `Symfony` framework using `Composer` or `PEAR` tools?

The same problem with older `Zend` and other frameworks. I need an old `Symfony` framework for running codes from books and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

**Symfony 1 via Pear**

1. required: PHP with PEAR installed
2. Add Symfony's PEAR archive: `pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com`
3. To find out the version number

   - browse http://pear.symfony-project.com/

     - please note that the version links allow manual downloads, e.g. http://pear.symfony-project.com//get/symfony-1.3.0.tgz
   - or `pear remote-list -c symfony`
4. Install

   - `pear install symfony/symfony`
   - or to install a specific version, like you requested: `pear install symfony/symfony-1.3.0`

**Symfony 1 via Composer**

The Composer repo for Symfony1 is https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony1

In order to install v1.3.19 add the following line to your `composer.json`'s `require` section:

`"symfony/symfony1": "1.3.19"`

or for latest v1 `"symfony/symfony1": "1.*"`

**Zend Framework 1 via Composer**

The Composer repo for ZF1 is  https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendframework1

In order to install v1.12.0 add the following line to your `composer.json`'s `require` section:

`"zendframework/zendframework1": "1.12.0"`

or latest v1 `"zendframework/zendframework1": "1.*"`